# Crear Aplicación Python Con Uso Restringido

Tags: python, windows, app

Eh creado una aplicación para Windows usando Python, y mi intención es que al crear un ejecutable para windows al iniciarse esa aplicación la primera vez de alguna forma se vincule al equipo donde se ejecuto, y  aun haciendo copias del ejecutable estas sigan vinculadas al mismo equipo, no se si algo así se pueda hacer algo similar a ello, me gustaría que me pudieran orientar en ello o si hay alguna fuente donde pueda investigar... Gracias!

Comment: Eso sería hacer un sistema de licencias, podrías utilizar alguno openSource para que no tengas que hacerlo todo. Por cierto, las preguntas que buscan consejos sobre recursos son propensas a opiniones y por lo tanto no cumplen con las normas del sitio por lo que es probable que la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente.

Comment: Hola @Juan J Mart, no hay forma de hacer imposible la copia, ahora si buscas algo sencillo, te doy una idea **gérmen**, generar un archivo durante la instalación, en el cual escribes la dirección **mac** de la máquina, tu programa antes de ejecutarse, verifica que la dirección de la máquina y la del archivo sean iguales y listo... o no, esto tiene un problema... que pasa si el usuario cambia la placa base...?